# Another way to express the idea of « Autant + infinitif »?

Tags: expressions

> [j’ai dit] : Un clavier ? C'est ce que tu appelles un cadeau romantique à offrir à ton amoureuse ? **Autant** lui donner une figurine de serpent !

The expression « Autant + infinitif » can be used sarcastically and emphatically to introduce a more exaggerated, extreme example than the already quite surprising idea mentioned in the preceding sentence.

I wonder if the following construction means more or less the same thing?

> Un clavier ? C'est ce que tu appelles un cadeau romantique à offrir à ton amoureuse ? **Sinon**, **tu pourrais aussi** lui donner une figurine de serpent !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding [**“pendant que tu y es”**](http://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/47756) or “tant que tu y es”  to your suggestion would probably sufficiently resolve the problem of ambiguity mentioned in two other answers (i.e., are you suggesting sarcastically that a snake figurine is equally (if not more) inappropriate for a romantic gift or are you seriously suggesting it as an acceptable romantic gift?):

> Un clavier ? C'est ce que tu appelles un cadeau romantique à offrir à
>   ton amoureuse ? Sinon, tu pourrais aussi lui donner une figurine de
>   serpent pendant que tu y es!

However, adding it to @SimonDéchamps' more idiomatic version of your suggestion would be the best way to stay close to your words and remove any lingering ambiguity, imo:

> Tu pourrais (tout) aussi bien lui donner une figurine de serpent
>   pendant que tu y es!

Personally, my second choice (after “**Autant** lui donner…”) would be asking sarcastically
 “**Pourquoi pas** [...X...] **pendant que tu y es?**,”
 either with the verb:

> Pourquoi pas lui donner une figurine de serpent pendant que tu y es?

… or without the it (because I think “cadeau romantique à offrir” would be understood):

> Pourquoi pas une figurine de serpent pendant que tu y es?

---

> **pendant que vous y êtes** & pendant que tu y es ; et pourquoi pas X pendant qu'ils y sont ; tant que tu y es – locution
>    Formule
>   d'exaspération ; formule de désobéissance ; formule ironique en
>   réponse à un souhait excessif

(from *languefrancaise.net/Bob*)

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of using “pendant que tu y es” in this instance, as I tend to associate this expression with "do X as well while you're at it (doing Y)". Merci. :)

Comment: *pendant qu'on y est* est plus courant comme impersonnel que *pendant qu'ils y sont*...

Answer (score 2):

"Autant lui donner une figurine de serpent !" express more the irony of the answer than "Sinon, tu pourrais aussi lui donner une figurine de serpent !", that suggests more a real alternative.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound idiomatic even if it *could* work.

Something like:

> Tu pourrais (tout) aussi bien lui donner...

... is a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

*Autant lui donner ...* is clearly sarcastic. *Tu pourrais aussi lui donner ...* is more context dependant. If no acceptable way has been given it would normally be interpreted the same, even if less emphatic. But it could be a possible alternative in another context (without the exclamation):

> Pour Marie, j'hésite entre un porte-monnaie et un clavier
>   
> Un clavier ... Tu pourrais aussi lui donner un réveil.

Without the exclamation it would sound like an acceptable gift, even if the remove the ambiguity, I would use *Tu pourrais plutôt ...* to introduce a positive alternative.

But anyway, *Autant lui donner ...* is much more expressive and idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

I probably would use something more in that tone :

> Un clavier ? C'est ce que tu appelles un cadeau romantique à offrir à
>   ton amoureuse ? **Donne** lui **carrément** une figurine de serpent !

"Carrément" would be used to give even more strength to the exaggeration.